# $ G$ be a group of order $30$ generated by $a$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> **Let G be a group of order $30$ generated by $a$. Then**
>
> **(i) find the order of the cyclic subgroup generated by $a^{18}$**
>
> **(ii) Find the subgroup $H$ of order $6$. Find the generator of $H$.**

To solve it, one can use the concept upto Lagrange's th.

Attempt:

We have $$o(a^{18})=\frac{30}{gcd(18, 30)}=\frac{30}{6}=5$$
Then order of the cyclic subgroup generated by $a^{18}$ is $5$.
(Please suggest the logic in more details.)

Please help for the 2nd part.

**EDIT For 2nd part (@kobe):**

$$o(a^5)=\frac{30}{gcd(5, 30)}=\frac{30}{5}=6$$. Please provide the logic to solve the 2nd part.

Comment: For (ii), consider $a^5$.

Comment: @kobe Why $a^5$? Please explore.

Comment: You've found that $o(a^5) = 6$, so you know that $a^5$ generates a cyclic subgroup $H$ of order $6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively speaking, the order of the cyclic group generated by $a^{18}$ is given by the equation you provide because clearing by the gcd guarantees that we "hit all multiples of $a^{18}$" in $G$. This fact can be verified using the Euclidean algorithm and the definition of the order of an element. (Notice that this means $g$ is a generator with order $k$ if and only if $\gcd(n,k) =1$, where $n$ is the order of the group). You can use your equation to find the subgroup of order $6$ generated by $a^5$. Namely, $\frac{30}{\gcd(5,30)} = \frac{30}{5} = 6$.

Comment: We are finding $o(a^{18})=5$ and claiming that order of the cyclic subgroup $=5$. Why the claim is true? Please supply reasons.

Comment: The order of the generator of a cyclic group is the order of the cyclic group.

Comment: thanks. Please explore the same for the 2nd part.

Comment: Same reason as part 1.

Comment: Not understand the 2nd part.